# Insert image to screen at touch co-ordinates by touch

Tags: java, android

i am making an app which requires an image to be placed on the screen at the location the user clicks. When user click second time the first image that appeared on the screen is gone..

```
if (motionEvent.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
    int x = (int) motionEvent.getX(); 
    int y = (int) motionEvent.getY(); 
    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams lp = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP‌​_CONTENT, RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT); 
    ImageView iv = new ImageView(getApplicationContext()); 
    lp.setMargins(x, y, 0, 0); 
    iv.setLayoutParams(lp); 
    iv.setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.a)‌​); 
    ((ViewGroup) view).addView(iv);
}
```

Comment: my code for inserting image is

Comment: post your code here. what have you done

Comment: if (motionEvent.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {int x =(int)motionEvent.getX(); int y = (int) motionEvent.getY();
  RelativeLayout.LayoutParams lp = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
                     ImageView iv = new ImageView(getApplicationContext());
                         lp.setMargins(x, y, 0, 0);
                         iv.setLayoutParams(lp);                         iv.setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.a));
                         ((ViewGroup) view).addView(iv);

Comment: #Prashant please ......